# SLES linux is not updating resolvers/nameservers from DHCP server

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, internal-dns, sles

I have two VMs in the same network - CentOS and SUSE linux. I didn't made any changes to configure DHCP client in these machines. When both the VMs are powered on, both the VMs are getting IPs but only CentOS getting the DHCP DNS hostname and resolvers/nameservers updated in /etc/resolve.conf properly whereas in SLES its not updating nameservers from DHCP server.

Does the SLES cannot fetch nameservers/resolvers from DHCP server? how to fix it?

I want the VMs to discover IP, DNS and resolvers automatically from the infoblox DHCP server. As I understand it, these VMs sends a broadcast message to 255.255.255.255. Typically a DHCP-relay catches this message and sends the request to the appropriate DHCP server. The DHCP server sends back a IP OFFER after which there is an exchange of REQUEST and ACKNOWLEDGE between the VM and the server.